Capture an Existing Lambda with a Data Element and Add an Environment Variable
The following construct below fails for me during the plan stage with the following error:

Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute with data.aws_lambda_function.rds_sqlserver_secret_rotation_lambda,
on rds-sql-staging.tf line 82, in data
"aws_lambda_function" "rds_sqlserver_secret_rotation_lambda":
82: data "aws_lambda_function"
"rds_sqlserver_secret_rotation_lambda" { Can't configure a value for
"environment": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.

An attempt is made below to add an enviroment variable to a newly created or previously existing Lamnda function via this configuration. There must be a preferred approach as the construct below is failing.
module "rds_sqlserver" {
  ...outputs secret_rotation_lambda_function_arn = function name
}

data "aws_lambda_function" "rds_sqlserver_secret_rotation_lambda" {
  function_name = module.rds_sqlserver.secret_rotation_lambda_function_arn
  environment {
    variables = {
      foo = "bar"
    }
  }
}

Update: I attempted a plan using just the function name and another using the function ARN. Both plans threw the same error above. Leads me to believe that what I am attempting to do is not directly supported.
